# PushingViewController from code

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

I'm having a problem switching between 2 view controllers. I have a supporting class called myViewController.
I want to click on a button in my main ViewController.m and go to this view.

I've looked on this site and found some code but can't get it to work in my code.

```
ViewController.m 


#import "myViewController.h"
-(void)viewDidLoad
{ //create button that will switch views 

UIButton *_buttonAccount = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [_buttonAccount setTitle:@"Create Account" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    _buttonAccount.frame = CGRectMake(110, 350, 95, 30);
    [_buttonAccount addTarget:self action:@selector(send:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:_buttonAccount];
}

-(void) send:(id)sender{

    myViewController *myViewController = [[myViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self presentModalViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
    [myViewController release];

}
```

Comment: Class name(`myViewController`) and XIB(`MyViewController`) name don't match. Not that its mandatory to do so. However check if you are passing the correct XIB name in the init method

Comment: I think the problem is at initWithNibName. You have written as MyViewController but it may be myViewController. Check it once.

Comment: Are you sure the NIB you are loading is MyViewController ? It is case sensitive.

Comment: @Andrea are you using navigation based class ?

Comment: Your code is correct, but this may be u r problem: MyViewController as myViewController for nib

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
-(void) send:(id)sender
{

        myViewController *myViewController = [[myViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:passview animated:NO];

 }
```

try this one really helpful to you.

Comment: Check the code, button action is added programmatically by `addTarget: action: forControlEvents:` method

Comment: @Jitendra Deore if we add target to button programatically then there is no necessity to use IBAction. You can use void too.

Comment: I changed it to make sure it said "myViewController" but it is still giving me the error " No visible @interface for myViewController' declares the selector 'alloc'

Comment: @Andrea F don't use myViewController as an instance name. You should give it any temporary name. otherwise it will give error

Answer (score 0):

Use this to present the VC

```
[self presentViewController: myViewController animated:YES completion:^{

    }] ;
```

Comment: Thank you everyone, changing the instance name was right. This code works for anyone else wondering.

-(void) send:(id)sender

{
SignupView *signupView = [[SignupView alloc] initWithNibName:@"myViewController" bundle:nil];


    [self presentModalViewController:signupView animated:YES];

}